# Schema.org ImageObject url

Tags: images, schema.org, microdata

Schema.org’s [`ImageObject`](https://schema.org/ImageObject) example uses `itemprop="contentUrl"`.

I tested this simplified code in Google: https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool gives me an error:

> A value for the url field is required

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">    
<div itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <img itemprop="contentUrl" src="1.png" alt="alt of the image">
    <p itemprop="caption">Caption of the image</p>
</div>
<h1 itemprop="name">Title of the post</h1>
<div itemprop="articleBody" class="text">       
    <p>This is the body of the post</p>
</div>
</div>
```

How to solve that error in Google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide the `url` property in addition to the `contentUrl` property:

```html
<img itemprop="contentUrl url" src="1.png" alt="alt of the image">
```

(Ideally Google would use/require `contentUrl` instead of `url` for the image for their [Article rich result](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/articles#article_types).)